# Xcode 5 How to go to Repositories window?

Tags: xcode, repository, xcode5

In previous XCode versions(4) I was able to click on Xcode and it would have 
Source Control -> Repositories

Now they have moved Source Control as a new drop down menu but it does not have Repositories part where I could check my SVN and see all other projects.

Is there a way to open Repositories window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create New Project  then check `Source Control`

[image]

```
then Menu Bar -> Source Control
```

[image]

**New Accounts preferences pane for managing Apple IDs, repositories, and continuous integration servers**  [New Features in Xcode 5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW14)

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I did not understand this one, it does not have trunk or anything like that??? And it also does not show history of it.

Answer (score 6):

With XCode 5, all repository management must be done by project.

Under the `Source Control` menu, choose the `master` working copy, then the `Configure <project>...` submenu. You will get to a dialog with three tabs. The second tab, `Remotes`, allows to add an existing remote to your project or create a new one.

For example, I usually create an empty GIT repository at my remote server, then I create the XCode project con local GIT repository, add the `ssh://<server>/<project>` remote address to the above project configuration, and then, the firs time I push the project, XCode connects to the remote repository, verifies that it is empty, and offers to push to the repository, creating it.