# Xcode 5 organiser not showing existing repositories

Tags: xcode5

I had 10 repositories connected to svn/github before Xcode5 update, however after updating to Xcode5 I do not know If I will get a change to look at all the connected repositories as in Xcode4.x. How do I get to see all the projects connected to svn/github?

Answer (score 3):

**I've figured it out:**

1, You can checkout, pull, commit, push **existing repositories** if you go to the menu **Source Control -> Checkout... and than, you have three tabs, Recents, Favourites, Repositories**.
That's where you find your repos.

2, You can **add new** repositories by going into the menu **XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts**

Answer (score 2):

I also have trouble with my repositories because the only option available to me is "Check Out..." despite my repositories are configured and enable in Xcode>Preferences>Account (see joined picture).

How do I update or commit my repositories now ?

[Screen shot of Xcode where all option for 'source control', but 'Check Out', are unvalaible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBWiD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Look in Xcode's Accounts preferences. Also take a look at the following question:

[Xcode 5 How to go to Repositories window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952465/xcode-5-how-to-go-to-repositories-window)