# In Xcode 5 getting error when i add the server under the source control

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, xcode5, source-control-explorer

When I create new project in Xcode 5, Am trying to add new server for source control. But am getting error alert like this "The Xcode service is disabled on this server. Please contact your administrator for help".

Comment: @pakashsys - please let me know whether my response has answered the question adequately or if not further refine your question.

Comment: @TommieC. Thanks for your answer, OSX Server is must for using github and subversion repositories in xcode ??... i have subversion server in windows environment.

Comment: As noted in my answer, you must use OSX server when you are prompted for a server name. If you want to save projects to a subversion server you will need to follow the directions in the link supplied in my answer.

Comment: @pakashsys OSX Server is not required for using github or subversion repositories in Xcode. The server name is useful if you want to manage  your projects under OSX Server or if you want to use the new bots integrations with OSX 10.9 Server. Hopefully the links in the answer provide enough information on connecting to github and subversion servers.

Comment: @TommieC. so we can add only OSX Servers in xcode am right ??

Comment: correct. One connects only to OSX Servers using this method.

Comment: @TommieC. Have one more doubt, i have check outed svn repository project. But the svn origin is not assigned. How can i assign remote url for commit the project to svn repository. This issue have any link with OSX Server. Reference image URL  https://www.dropbox.com/s/po7splrc0hmq39h/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-14%20at%205.28.52%20PM.png

Comment: That is a different question. I recommend you search stack overflow for the answer or ask another question. If my answer is helpful for you original question please accept the answer by clicking the checkbox. This will help raise your reputation and encourage others to respond to future questions. BTW - You may find additional info at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972985/xcode-5-organiser-not-showing-existing-repositories

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check out how to turn on the OSX Server Xcode service at the following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/200-Adopting_a_Continuous_Integration_Workflow/adopt_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH3-SW1.

If review of this guide does not fix your issue please let me know more specifics about your environment. If it does help please consider accepting the answer so others will locate the resource.

**Important Conceptual Notes:**

When you setup a new project and you are offered a server this refers to an OSX Server only (not github or any non-OSX external server):

[image: Add new server]

So basically just make sure the OSX Xcode service is ON or restart your 10.9+ OSX server if possible...

[image: Enable Xcode Service on OSX Server]

NB: If what you want to do is to push your repository to github.com or code.google.com please see the following links for instructions on getting this to run in Terminal. Once the link between the remote repository and your local directory then Xcode will be able to push updates to your remote repositories (this will be available as a checkbox when you commit your project).

[Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote)

[Pushing to Google Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961619/how-to-push-local-git-repo-to-newly-created-google-code-project)

Comment: For adding the OS X Xcode service to the Xcode, is it necessary to add a apple account under Developer teams in Server.??

Comment: @NOOB In order to access the server externally you will need to configure the settings after enabling the service. I have added my apple account under developer teams and enabled individual user access under permissions. I haven't tried to remove the apple account to test for impact so I am uncertain of the result if one were to leave this empty.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want to add a [repository](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/add_repository.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH4-SW1), not an [XCode Continuous Integration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html) server.
Adding a server is adding an XCode Continuous Integration server.
Use add repository instead. See the guide in the first link.

Comment: suppose I have a OSX server configured in a different location and i add my OSX server using url in my Xcode. Now, I want to create bot from my Xcode for a repository then how to do it?? My repositories are hosted on entirely different server as compared to my machine and the one hosting OSX server. All three in different locations.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a "Server" in apple's definition is not a BitBucket server or GitHub server, it has to be a server that you host by yourself. Otherwise you are looking at adding a "repository".

I got enlightened by the screenshot below, note the server address:

[image: repo]